# can't print in 22.04

Tags: printing, hp

I hope someone can help me fix this issue.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, I have been for about 2 months now with hardly any problems until Friday. In Libre Office Writer (the default version that installs with Ubuntu 22.04), my HP printer suddenly stopped working even though I haven't changed anything at all.

I haven't tried printing from other apps, should I? The LO Writer app shows my printer name. When I looked at my print queue, everything *looked* OK.

I did a little research & tried the following in terminal:

```
lpstat(1)
```

the result was:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `1'
```

I've no idea what this means, I'm hoping someone can tell me or even if is my issue?
Anyone can help me.

Comment: Just type "lpstat" not "lpstat(1)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo apt install hplip` then

try visit `http://localhost:631/admin` and delete and re-add printer here.

Note, it works only in Firefox. Not Chrome or Vivaldi.

Comment: I tried to <add a printer>. CUPS will not allow my username & password. Any ideas?

Comment: username is same as output of `whoami` command in terminal. So If you have username "PieLam" it's most probably "pielam" in CUPS.

Comment: Success, many thanx!!! But now I don't what all I should select... Below is the output of <add printer>
BTW, my HP printer is a wireless printer. I disabled serial & parallel ports long ago.

Comment: Local Printers:  CUPS-BRF (Virtual Braille BRF Printer)
    HP Printer (HPLIP)
Serial Port #1
    HP Fax (HPLIP)
Discovered Network Printers:  HP OfficeJet Pro 9010 [5E0089] (HP OfficeJet 
                         HP OfficeJet Pro 9010 (driverless) (HP OfficeJet Pro 9010)
       HP OfficeJet Pro 9010 (HP OfficeJet Pro 9010)
Other Network Printers:  AppSocket/HP JetDirect
      Backend Error Handler
      Internet Printing Protocol (h)
      Internet Printing Protocol (i)
      LPD/LPR Host or Printer
      Internet Printing Protocol (h)
      Internet Printing Protocol (i)

Comment: I think it would be "HP OfficeJet Pro 9010 [5E0089]" even tho not sure, depends on what Printer you have, and it's not really visible from comment what is end of printer name and start of another one, as well as in which categories they show (local, network, others).

Comment: It may help if you knew more about my printer... It's is an HP 9015 All-in-one. Fax, Scan, ink jet. As stated previously, I use the wireless connection. No USB, Parallel or Serial ports are in use. 

I just can't understand why it did this all of a sudden, I haven't changed a thing. (mostly for fear of breaking something)...

As you may already have guessed, I am pretty new to Linux/Ubuntu even though I've been using PCs for almost 40 years. :)

Comment: BTW, sorry about the garbled CUPS output. This forum software took out all my nice formatting. :(